# Cannot install packages with apt-get update in debian (Proxy)

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, proxy

I have Debian 10 installed in my Virtual Machine and want to use

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Problem is I am in a network with an internet connection over proxy. So far so good, I set up the automatic proxy address and also set up IvP4 as it is set up in Windows. I can normally browse the internet with my VM, but when I want to use the bash mentioned earlier I get the error message that it is not able to establish the connection and download files.

I found this

```
sudo http_proxy='http://user:pass@proxy.example.com:8080/'
apt-get install package-name
```

but my attempts on using this all failed.

So do anyone knows a solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

Create a `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/http-proxy.conf` with the following line:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://user:pass@proxy.example.com:8080/";
```

Then run:

```
export http_proxy=http://user:pass@proxy.example.com:8080/
```

Or add it to your `~/.bashrc` .

```
sudo apt install package_name
```

Debian FAQ: [Q: How do I tell {{{apt-get}}} which http-proxy to use?](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianFAQ)

> A: Set the environment Variable `http_proxy`: `export http_proxy="http://192.168.1.1:8080"` or `export http_proxy=http://uid:pw@proxy:port` if the proxy needs authentication. Alternatively you can configure it in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`

Comment: You may also have to acquire the https proxy: `Acquire::https::Proxy "http://user:password@proxy.example.com:XXXX/"`

Comment: Okay thank you, but one question I ran into earlier. Do you have an example on how to fill (http::Proxy "http://user:pass@proxy.example.com:8080/")?

Comment: @BaB Welcome , just use your proxy credentials , user, pass and the address.